# CTE in mysql does NOT work with group by having clause

Tags: mysql, group-by, common-table-expression, having

I have following scenario with Project table:
Goal is to write a SQL query that reports all the projects that have the most employees.

Table **Project**:

| project_id | employee_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 |

Expected Output:

| project_id |
| --- |
| 1 |

I wrote following query using `CTE` but it's NOT working. It's throwing a syntax error when I try to use cte query as subquery in group by having clause.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT COUNT(employee_id) AS mxcnt 
    FROM Project 
    GROUP BY project_id 
    ORDER BY mxcnt DESC 
    LIMIT 1 
)
SELECT project_id 
FROM Project 
GROUP BY project_id 
HAVING COUNT(employee_id) = SELECT mxcnt FROM cte
```

I also replaced subquery with "*cte.mxcnt*" and that didn't work either

Answer (score 1):

This would get you all projects that have the max number of employees.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Project  (
>   `project_id` INTEGER,
>   `employee_id` INTEGER
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO Project 
>   (`project_id`, `employee_id`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '1'),
>   ('1', '2'),
>   ('1', '3'),
>   ('2', '1'),
>   ('2', '4');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>     `project_id`
> FROM Project
> GROUP BY `project_id`
> HAVING COUNT(*) = 
> (SELECT  COUNT(*) _countr FROM Project  GROUP BY `project_id` ORDER BY _countr DESC LIMIT 1)
> ```
>
> ```
> | project_id |
> | ---------: |
> |          1 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f62d5f5ac8e82415eb1bc354bf2e9d80)*